# How to split String to int and bytestring literal

Tags: django, string, python-3.x, byte

I have the following string:

`str = "3, b'\\xf3\\xc71\\xe9\\xad_\\xce\\x8bI\\x1c\\x04Y\\xd5z\\xa2Q'"`

I need to split it in order to get two variables, an int and a bytestring like so:

```
number = 3
bytestring = b'\\xf3\\xc71\\xe9\\xad_\\xce\\x8bI\\x1c\\x04Y\\xd5z\\xa2Q'
```

What I tried doing:

```
number, bytestring = [s for s in str.split(", ")]
int_number = int(number)
bytestring_in_bytes = bytestring.encode()
```

This unfortunately didn't work for the bytestring and I ended up with something like this:

`bytesring_in_bytes = b"b'\\xf3\\xc71\\xe9\\xad_\\xce\\x8bI\\x1c\\x04Y\\xd5z\\xa2Q'"`

Any idea how to get the bytestring from the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you here have seems like the textual representation (in Python the `repr(..)`) of a bytestring.

You can use `ast.literal_eval(..)` to convert this to a bytestring:

```
from ast import literal_eval

bytestring_in_bytes = literal_eval(bytestring)
```

Note that in case it contains a `str`ing, `int`, etc., then the type of `bytestring_in_bytes` will be a `str`, `int`, etc. as well.